# using passed arguments in bash script

Tags: bash

I am passing two date values to a script and trying to use those in a CURL POST command as below:

```
starttime=$1
endtime=$2

for apps in $(cat testapps.txt)
do
    curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1" -d '{"name": "This is a test","timeRange": {"startTimeMillis":"$1","endTimeMillis":"$2"}, "affects": {"type": "APP"}}'
```

It is giving me 500 internal server error.

If I replace the $1 and $2 value with the date/time as below, it works fine.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1" -d '{"name": "This is a test","timeRange": {"startTimeMillis":"2019-05-28T15:00:00-0400","endTimeMillis":"2019-05-28T16:00:00-0400"}, "affects": {"type": "APP"}}'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: you are using the variables `$1 and $2` inside single quotes. see after `-d` you are using single quotes. In bash you cannot expand the variable when its inside single quote. Try using double quotes.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Getting this error when I replace single quote with double - curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: a; Unknown error
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 120

Comment: you need to properly escape it before using it, as the input  json already contains double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Answer (score 1):

First, [Dont Read Lines With For](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

```
while read apps
do args=( 
    -X POST
    -H "Content-type: application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1"
    -d '{ "name":"This is a test",
          "timeRange": { 
              "startTimeMillis": "'"$1"'",
              "endTimeMillis": "'"$2"'" }, 
          "affects": {"type": "APP"}}'
   ) 
   # don't you need a URL here?
   curl "${args[@]}" "$apps" # added $apps, assuming that was missing...
done < testapps.txt
```